# Sql - Getting Sum on the join table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to get the result which displays the reference which is not tallied in sum of table2. when i run my query below it will give me an wrong sum which it gets doubled even if group by cusid ,refno.

Table 1

| RefNo | CusID | TotalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 50 |
| 2 | 1001 | 30 |
| 3 | 1002 | 40 |

Table 2

| RefNo | CusID | Particular | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | Paper | 30 |
| 1 | 1001 | Pencil | 30 |
| 2 | 1001 | Ball | 15 |
| 2 | 1001 | Rubber | 20 |
| 3 | 1002 | Laptop | 50 |

```
select * from Table1  a
INNER JOIN (Select CusID,RefNo, SUM(Amount) as CorrectTotal from Table2 group by 
    CusID,RefNo,            
    )b
ON b.CusID= a.CusID AND b.RefNo= a.RefNo
where a.TotalAmount != CorrectTotal
```

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Please add expected and actual output

Comment: In truth, the above errors, due to `,RefNo, )b` in the subquery. If you fix that, however, the `SUM`s look fine to me. The `SUM` of 30 and 30 is 60, the sum of 15 and 30 is 35, and the sum of 50 is 50; that's the result in the query. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=12d44095c5a8c758caadf9971f4f0f92)

Comment: I must admit, I'm not a fan of these tables, for copying and putting into an IDE they do the worst thing possible; they use tabs... That isn't helpful.

Comment: That is the result you get, @CodeSeven ... As the fiddle I linked demonstrates.

Comment: @Larnu That's a failure of the IDE, not the table here. They paste perfectly into Excel for example, and it's not hard to do a find/replace on tabs

Comment: I disagree, @DavidA , it's not a failure to copy tabs as tabs... If I copied something and it changed the characters, that *would* be a failure.

Comment: @Larnu There are no tabs in the markup above. It's your IDE trying to be clever with pasting HTML into a window that wasn't designed to format text that way.

Comment: So you're saying *your* IDE pastes the data as fixed width, @DavidG ?

Comment: @Larnu You're the one that said it used tabs

Comment: Cause it does, @DavidG , clearly you're saying yours does not, so I can only assume it pastes as fixed width, no? That is, after all, the desired format. If you are saying yours does tabs as well, why do you disagree that the tabs are "helpful" when they are the complete opposite; they are ***not*** helpful...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say now @Larnu. You complained that pasting these tables into your IDE uses tabs. I actually don't think that's a bad thing (not that I would be pasting these into my IDE in the first place)

Comment: @codeSeven, Seems you have typo in the "expected results". CustID in last row should be 1002 not 1001

Comment: Another benefit of having these tables is that you can write a simple extension that will let you copy them into any format that works best for you.

Comment: *"not that I would be pasting these into my IDE in the first place"* no, I would be pasting the fixed width text in, that was original in the question... -_- I'm not going to transcribe that into my IDE to test, that would be awful @DavidG . So what is the best way to do it? To copy and paste... If you transcribe, that's up to you, but certainly copy and pasting a **consumable** format is far better. But we're way off topic here, if you prefer tabs, that's up to you, but I know that the SQL community truly hate them in sample data.

Comment: @Larnu I don't 'prefer' tabs, it's just how the IDE decides that HTML tables are represented in text form. If it helps, I've made you a TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey script that will copy these tables into a nice CSV for you :) https://github.com/WiredUK/TamperScripts/blob/main/table-formatter.user.js

Answer (score 0):

If you do it with `FULL JOIN` and with `GROUP BY`, you will also get rows where there is no record in the other table.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(a.RefNo, b.RefNo) AS RefNo
     , COALESCE(a.CusID, b.CusID) AS CusID
     , a.TotalAmount
     , SUM(b.Amount) AS CorrectTotal
  FROM table1 a
  FULL JOIN table2 b ON a.RefNo = b.RefNo
                    AND a.CusID = b.CusID
 GROUP BY COALESCE(a.RefNo, b.RefNo)
        , COALESCE(a.CusID, b.CusID)
        , a.TotalAmount
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

*Output*

| RefNo | CusID | TotalAmount | CorrectTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 50 | 60 |
| 2 | 1001 | 30 | 35 |
| 3 | 1002 | 40 | 50 |
| 8 | 888 | 88 | (null) |
| 9 | 999 | (null) | 99 |

See running demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87b09/3).

Answer (score 0):

The other answer will work, but if you don't want to mess with a `GROUP BY` on the whole query you can also use an `APPLY` to do this:

```
SELECT a.*, c.CorrectAmount
FROM Table1 a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS CorrectAmount 
    FROM Table2 b 
    WHERE b.CusID = a.CusID AND b.RefNo = a.RefNo
) c
WHERE a.TotalAmount <> c.CorrectAmount
```